# Rotate 2d sprite towards pointer

Tags: 2d, javascript, rotation, crafty, mathematics

I'm using Crafty.js and am trying to point a sprite towards the mouse pointer.

I have a function for getting the degree between two points and I'm pretty sure it works mathematically (I have it under unit tests). At least it responds that the degree between { 0,0} and {1,1} is 45, which seems right.

However, when I set the sprite rotation to the returned degree, it's just wrong all the time. If I manually set it to 90, 45, etc, it gets the right direction..

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UkbhD/5/) that shows what I've done so far.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some experimentation, your angle appears to be inverted, but otherwise correct. Negating your angle works:

```
obj1.rotation = -Engine.degree(pos2, pos1);
```

And the [modified jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UkbhD/6/).